# PostgreSQL Generated Column is not always up to date

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

**Version**: PostgreSQL 12.4

**Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id int16 NOT NULL,
    placed_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    picked_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    packed_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    generated_status int2 NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (calculate_status(placed_count, picked_count, packed_count)) STORED,
    CONSTRAINT table1_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

**Function**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_status(
placed_count integer, 
picked_count integer, 
packed_count integer
)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE sql
 IMMUTABLE STRICT
AS $function$
select
    case
        when placed_count <= 0 then 1 --pending
        when packed_count = placed_count then 3 --packed
        when picked_count = placed_count then 2 --picked
        else 4 --else
    end
$function$
;
```

The generated_status generated column is not up to date on some records and doesn't match the result of running the function with the same values found on that row.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Table1 tt
WHERE generated_status  != 
calculate_status
(
  tt.placed_count, 
  tt.picked_count, 
  tt.packed_count
)
```

returns a positive count.

The rows I usually have trouble with are:

| ID | placed_count | picked_count | packed_count | generated_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 |

When I input the values into the function they do return 3, but it seems to me that the generated column is not updating for the last placed count update sometimes or its value gets over-written by some concurrency issue/ race condition.

What could be wrong, this doesn't happen a lot (~30 in 100k) but I need this status to be always up to date or it will cause some trouble.

Comment: I think the code for this function `calculate_status()` would be needed to know why it fails with certain values.

Comment: The function doesn't fail with certain values. The result for the function is different than the value of the generated column.

Ex:
calculate_status(v1, v2, v3) -> 1
You might find a row with:
(id, v1, v2, v3, 2)

Comment: Added the function anyways

Comment: `when placed_count = placed_count` seems to be true always ?

Comment: Corrected the example:
packed_count = placed_count

Comment: Maybe you can provide a [mre] ?  I tried to reproduce your problem, but was not successful, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/_GPtZ_H4

Comment: I can't replicate the concurrency and PSQL version on dbfiddle.

Comment: From the release notes of 12.5: [Ensure that GENERATED columns are updated when the column(s) they depend on are updated via a rule or an updatable view (Tom Lane)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/12.5/#:~:text=Ensure%20that%20GENERATED%20columns%20are%20updated%20when%20the%20column(s)%20they%20depend%20on%20are%20updated%20via%20a%20rule%20or%20an%20updatable%20view%20(Tom%20Lane))   My conclusion will be that you need an update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way this could happen (barring bugs) is if you changed the definition of the function.  Doing so will not cause the value for the pre-existing rows to be recomputed.

UPDATE: I was able to reproduce this and filed [a bug report](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAMkU%3D1xBMZ1-qq3%2Bef-j75g-X2JN%2BcZdDm_pGou9gceBvhqe_w%40mail.gmail.com), which has the reproducer case attached to it.

Comment: The function definition did indeed change and there are some old inconsistencies, but newly updated records are also having the issue.
I will cleanse the issue by applying a dummy update but I need to stop the problem first.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that you are mistaken.  Newly updated records would only get fixed if the update changed one of the columns used in the expression.  Otherwise they would persist in their inconsistency.

Comment: Yes, but newly created rows have the same issue sometimes.
I couldn't find any detailed information in the documentation.

Could it be a bug related to concurrent updates?

Comment: Please share the values of this "newly created records". Normally it would be a reproducible problem when you create another records with these values.

Comment: Values I have trouble with are those at status 3
ID Placed Picked Packed Status
1   3          3          3           2 (Should be 3)
2   4          4          4           2 (Should be 3)
When I input the values into the function they do return 3, but it seems to me that the generated column is not updating for the last placed count update sometimes or its value gets over-written by some concurrency issue/ race condition.